# Grails: unable to resolve class Validatable , unable to find class for annotation

Tags: grails

I'm working on a legacy Grails `2.3.11` application. When I annotate a command class with `grails.validation.Validateable`, it seems unable to find it. However `@Validatable` works fine on another Grails `2.5.6` application. Was the annotation introduced after 2.3.11?

Comment: import grails.validation.Validateable

@Validateable

Comment: @JMa I know how to import and annotate. I'm just curious why the class can't be found.

Comment: do you have `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.Validateable` available?

Comment: The code at https://github.com/jeffbrown/validateableavailability/blob/98b901a9b1f600f1249117ead98e04ad1a5e86f8/src/groovy/demo/SomeValidateable.groovy#L5 appears to compile without issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Was the annotation introduced after 2.3.11?

No.  It is included in 2.3.11.  See https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/v2.3.11/grails-plugin-validation/src/main/groovy/grails/validation/Validateable.java.

Comment: I found out that it actually works in 2.3.11. It's IntelliJ that couldn't find it.

Comment: That indicates that the project isn't configured properly in the IDE.  IntelliJ is definitely capable of finding it when the project is properly configured.  Without seeing it it is hard to say what is wrong but likely the dependencies are out of sync.  Best of luck.